# Include link to HTML/CSS validator in local HTML file

Tags: html, css

I have a local HTML file with embedded CSS, not intended for being used in a web server, just as a printing template so it remains a *local* file. And no, I can't put this on any web server to solve my problem. And yes, I know I can run a local copy of the validator, but this file is going to be used in environments where that cannot be done, so...

Since I have to validate it from time to time, when some modifications are made to this file, I thought about adding some links to the HTML/CSS online validator I use (the W3C one) at the end of the file. Unfortunately, these links only work if the HTTP client sends a `Referer` header, and being a local file... well, the web browser doesn't send that header.

The link I'm using for HTML validation is:

```
<a href="http://validator.w3.org/check/referer" rel="nofollow" title="Validate">Validate</a>
```

And of course the validator spews a `No Referer header found!` error.

For CSS this is even more complicated, as the validator (at far as I know) doesn't use the `Referer` header, so I don't even know how to proceed in this case.

The HTML validator has some kind of experimental API which I can use by sending the current file as multipart/form-data, but I'd love to use a simpler solution.

How can I add some links to the local HTML file so it can be validated automatically? I can use some embedded JavaScript if that's the only way, but I would prefer a simple solution...

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, at least not with client-side code.

The Validator has to be able to access the source code of the page in order to validator it.

The usual way it does this is to access it via a public-facing URL. Your local pages don't have one of those.

The other standard ways are via file upload and pasting the code into a textarea. It also has an API, as you mentioned, but I don't know if that supports the validator.nu engine.

All three of the above methods require that you have access to the HTML source code of the page — which you don't from client-side code. The closest you could come would be to serialize the DOM of the page back to HTML … which would give you the results *after* your browser has performed error recovery on it. That would be useless for validation.

---

Make validation part of your *development* workflow rather than your published result. For example, you could use something like [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Umoxfo.vscode-w3cvalidation) for VS Code.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer and the clarification. I was assuming there were some kind of hidden method I didn't know about for doing this but it's obvious there isn't any...   The solution I'm using now it's the one you propose: I do the validation myself before publishing the file, but the problem is that some users WANT to do their validation (long story) so I thought about adding the buttons.